# Description of "Marshal" badge?

Tags: support, badges

Please, see image given below:

[image]

But, I'd received already on 23 may,16.

[image]

My question is:

> > Can "Marshal" be awarded multiple time? Please, describe "Marshal" badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description is simple. If you have reached 500 helpful flags, then you get the Marshal badge. That's it.

It cannot be awarded multiple times. However, yesterday during some server upgrade, there was a bug that essentially awarded a lot of people, all across the network, two extra Marshal badges. This was fixed, and now we are back to the expected behavior of the badge. Which means it does not get awarded multiple times.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23407/18398

Comment: Now these awarded "Marshal" badges, will be back as they already were?

Comment: @Mithlesh: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The extraneous badges are gone. People who should have the badge, have it, and they have it exactly the right number of times it should be awarded to them: once.